# How to make a backup of my app (iPad)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

i am new in programming and have some troubles with backup.
I have an App with SQLite database and different user params in it. All data will be saved, after I leave application. But if I reinstall it, all data is lost. 
So, i think i need some kind of backup for this data. I mean is there any way, how to save SQLite db outside of apps folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updating the application will not overwrite your data**, but deleting the app will remove all data. You don't need to delete the application each time you redeploy to your device or simulator.

Your application doesn't have access to anything outside of it's sandbox, so saving outside the apps folder is out of the question.